# How to parse a dynamic string to find key-value pairs in it

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have a data packet in following JSON format.

```
[{"C74": "123"}, {"C75": "32"}, {"C76": "11"}, {"C78": "15"}]
```

Is it possible to parse in following C# model?

```
{
   string key { get; set; }
   string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are the keys unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your string is not a `Dictionary` it's a `Dictionary[]`

So you have to deserialize it that way and convert it into your desired format.

```
string input = "[{\"C74\": \"123\"}, {\"C75\": \"32\"}, {\"C76\": \"11\"}, {\"C78\": \"15\"}]";
Dictionary<string, string>[] temp = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(input);
Dictionary<string, string> result = temp.Select(x => x.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can parse it to a List, for example

```
List<Item> items = JArray.Parse(json)
                         .SelectMany(ja => ((JObject)ja).Properties()
                         .Select(x => new Item { key = x.Name, 
                                                 value = (string)x.Value })
                         ).ToList();

public class Item
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```